# Using glassfish gem (or other webserver) with SSL

Tags: ssl, glassfish, jruby

My goal is to deploy a simple rails application on a windows server using the glassfish **gem**.

I have no trouble getting the glassfish gem to work with regular http, however I now need to add SSL security and I cannot find any links on how to enable **https** in the glassfish gem.

Has anyone succeeded in setting up the glassfish gem to support SSL?

Are there any other ways to serve a rails application over SSL on windows without any additional software installation (e.g. IIS, Glassfish, jBoss)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use jetty-rails gem and I coded SSL support in it.
If you choose to use jetty-rails as well you can follow these instructions to add SSL.
Make sure you use jetty-rails version 0.6 as current 0.8.1 is buggy.
I'm sure that GlassFish too can be made to use SSL in a similar way.
I chose Jetty as it seems faster (startup) smaller and easier to change the source.

#### jetty_rails-0.6/lib/jetty_rails/server.rb +32

```
  if config[:ssl] and config[:ssl] == true
    if config[:keystore] =~ /^\\/ # starts with slash => absolute dir
      keystore = config[:keystore]
    else # assume keystore is in cofig dir
      keystore = @config[:base] + '/config/' + config[:keystore]
    end
    if not config[:truststore].nil? # have separate truststore
      if config[:truststore] =~ /^\\/ # starts with slash => absolute dir
        truststore = config[:truststore]
      else # assume keystore is in cofig dir
        truststore = @config[:base] + '/config/' + config[:truststore]
      end
    else # trustore == keystore
      truststore = keystore
    end

    security_connector = Jetty::Security::SslSocketConnector.new
    security_connector.set_acceptors(config[:acceptor_size])
    security_connector.port = config[:port]
    security_connector.confidential_port = config[:port]
    security_connector.keystore = keystore
    security_connector.password = config[:password]
    security_connector.key_password = config[:key_password].nil? ? config[:password] : config[:key_password]
    security_connector.truststore = truststore
    security_connector.trust_password = config[:trust_pasword].nil? ? config[:password] : config[:trust_pasword]
    @server.add_connector(security_connector)
  else
    connector = Jetty::SelectChannelConnector.new
    connector.set_acceptors(config[:acceptor_size])
    connector.port = config[:port]
    connector.confidential_port = config[:security_port] if config[:security_port]
    @server.add_connector(connector)
  end
```

#### how to generate a certificate store (keystore.jks)

See here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+configure+SSL

#### RAILS_ROOT/config/jetty_rails.yml

```
# Config
:port: 3000
:jruby_min_runtimes: <%= config[:environment] == 'production' ? 3 : 1 %>
:jruby_max_runtimes: <%= config[:environment] == 'production' ? 6 : 2 %>
:thread_pool_max: 40
:thread_pool_min: 4
:acceptor_size: 10

# Security
:ssl: true
:keystore: keystore.jks
:password: your_pass
# :key_password: your_pass # if different
# :truststore: truststore.jks # if different
# :trust_pasword: your_pass # if different
```

#### start the server

```
jruby -S jetty_rails -c config/jetty_rails.yml
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In addition to what you mentioned above I had to add the following lines to lib/jars.rb 

    module Security
      include_package "org.mortbay.jetty.security"
    end

For the project in question I have switched to using Jetty + WAR distribution, i.e. I am not using Jetty rails but rather the standard Jetty version and package my application using warbler.